# Serialization inside ASP.Net MVC Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, thread-safety

Updated question:
With or without lock statement, the behavior is the same. So likely I am missing some configuration which is making action execution one thread at a time.

Previous question:
My understanding is that thread acquires lock only during the scope of execution of statements within brackets of lock { }. But from logs it appears as if the whole method is under lock statement.

Here is sample code:

```cs
public class HomeController
{
    public static int VisitCounter { get; set; }
    static object locker = new object();
    public string Index()
    {
        var tid = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        System.Console.WriteLine($"Method Enter:{tid} {DateTime.Now}");
        // lock (locker)  // commented for updated question
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine($"Lock Enter  :{tid} {DateTime.Now}");
            VisitCounter++;
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            System.Console.WriteLine($"Lock Exit   :{tid} {DateTime.Now}");
        }
        System.Console.WriteLine($"Method Exit :{tid} {DateTime.Now}");
        return $"Hello. You are visitor number: {VisitCounter}.";
    }
}
```

Actual Output:
Both threads appear serialized at method-level.

```
Method Enter:10 3/10/2021 10:00:00 AM
Lock Enter  :10 3/10/2021 10:00:00 AM
Lock Exit   :10 3/10/2021 10:00:05 AM
Method Exit :10 3/10/2021 10:00:05 AM
Method Enter:11 3/10/2021 10:00:05 AM
Lock Enter  :11 3/10/2021 10:00:05 AM
Lock Exit   :11 3/10/2021 10:00:10 AM
Method Exit :11 3/10/2021 10:00:10 AM
```

Expected Output:
Both http requests should arrive at method approx at the same time, but only one should enter locked section of code at a time. Only locked section should be serialized.

```
Method Enter:10 3/10/2021 10:00:00 AM
Method Enter:11 3/10/2021 10:00:02 AM
Lock Enter  :10 3/10/2021 10:00:00 AM
Lock Exit   :10 3/10/2021 10:00:05 AM
Lock Enter  :11 3/10/2021 10:00:05 AM
Method Exit :10 3/10/2021 10:00:05 AM
Lock Exit   :11 3/10/2021 10:00:10 AM
Method Exit :11 3/10/2021 10:00:10 AM
```

---

Just for reference, here is Startup.cs

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
        });
    }
}
```

---

**Steps to recreate:**

1. dotnet new web
2. Place controller code in Controllers folder.
3. Update startup code
4. Run it: dotnet run

Comment: I see no reason for the behavior you observe, based on the code you have posted. Do you have any other layer of synchronization forgotten around your code? What happens if you comment out the `lock (locker)` statement?

Comment: what if you changed your method to be asynchronous? and used a `new SemaphoreSlim(1)` to do your synchronization?

Comment: I added rest of the files and steps to recreate the whole solution. TIA.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I removed the lock and you are correct, it something more than that. Still the same serialization. Based on your tip, I also changed launchSettings.json (set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to Production). No change.